# How can i use FFMpeg in laravel 6 with this config?

Tags: laravel, ffmpeg-php

my system config is:

- windows 10
- Xampp v3.2.3 installed in D Drive
- php v7.3.4
- composer is installed

I install FFMpeg and run this command: `composer require php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg`
when I test it in one .php file it is work correctly but when i want to use it in Laravel v6
show me this error:

> Class 'FFMpeg\FFProbe' not found

Answer (score 1):

AS Vikas said you have to add `use FFMpeg;` in top of your code and if you want to use FFProbe you can use this syntax:

```
        $ffprobe = FFMpeg\FFProbe::create();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use super easy wrapper of PHP-FFMpeg for laravel

https://github.com/protonemedia/laravel-ffmpeg